# Aggregating several columns to single column

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table that looks like

```
id      cat     data
--------------------
1       1       foo
2       1       bar
3       1       baz
4       2       some
5       2       random
6       3       Data 1
7       2       data
8       3       Data 2
9       3       Data 3
```

And I want the last 3 `id`s and `data` of each category in a single row like

```
cat     id1     data1   id2     data2   id3     data3
-----------------------------------------------------
1       1       foo     2       bar     3       baz
2       4       some    5       random  7       data
3       6       Data 1  8       Data 2  9       Data 3
```

I already tried the following:

- Get the data with the highest `id` for each `cat`:

  ```
  SELECT id, data FROM tbl t1 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t1.cat = t2.cat 
      GROUP BY t2.cat HAVING MAX(t2.id) = t1.id
  )
  ```
- Get the data with the 2<sup>nd</sup> highest `id`s for each `cat`:

  ```
  SELECT id, data FROM tbl t1 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t1.cat = t2.cat AND NOT EXISTS (
          -- Not the highest value
          SELECT 1 FROM tbl t3 WHERE t1.cat = t3.cat GROUP BY t3.cat
          HAVING MAX(t3.id) = t2.id
      ) GROUP BY t2.cat HAVING MAX(t2.id) = t1.id
  )
  ```
- Get the data with the 3<sup>rd</sup> highest `id` for each `cat`:

  ```
  SELECT id, data FROM tbl t1 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t1.cat = t2.cat AND NOT EXISTS (
          -- id is not 2nd highest
          SELECT 1 FROM tbl t3 WHERE t1.cat = t3.cat AND NOT EXISTS (
              -- id is not the highest
              SELECT 1 FROM tbl t4 WHERE t1.cat = t4.cat GROUP BY t4.cat
              HAVING MAX(t4.id) = t3.id
          ) GROUP BY t3.cat HAVING MAX(t3.id) = t2.id
      ) AND NOT EXIST (
          -- not the highest id
          SELECT 1 FROM tbl t5 WHERE t1.cat = t5.cat GROUP BY t5.cat
          HAVING MAX(t5.id) = t2.id
      ) GROUP BY t2.cat HAVING MAX(t2.id) = t1.id
  )
  ```

And now, joining the entire thing.  But I believe that there exists a better solution.  What is it?

PS: I have to do it with Informix

Comment: If you can use a Stored Procedure, it would give you the flexibility to do it in stages, referring to previous Max values. I would probably start by writing an SP to retrieve the Max id for a specified cat, then the max WHERE id<that, then the Max WHERE id<that, then return a row comprised of the 3 sets of values. This SP would then be called by a simple query of grouped cats.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only read access to the database.

Comment: Then I wish you luck, I'm all out of ideas (apart from exporting the data to MS SQL or Postgres and doing it with CTEs!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my answer, a coworker of mine came up with this:

```
create temp table t(
    id      smallint,
    cat     smallint,
    data    char(10)
) with no log;

insert into t values (1, 1, "foo");
insert into t values (2, 1, "bar");
insert into t values (3, 1, "baz");
insert into t values (4, 2, "some");
insert into t values (5, 2, "random");
insert into t values (6, 3, "Data 1");
insert into t values (7, 2, "data");
insert into t values (8, 3, "Data 2");
insert into t values (9, 3, "Data 3");
insert into t values (10, 4, "some");
insert into t values (11, 4, "more");
insert into t values (12, 4, "random");
insert into t values (13, 4, "data");
insert into t values (14, 4, "for");
insert into t values (15, 4, "testing");
insert into t values (16, 5, "one");

select
   cat,
   max(case when cnt = 3 then id end) as id1,
   max(case when cnt = 2 then id end) as id2,
   max(case when cnt = 1 then id end) as id3,
   max(case when cnt = 3 then data end) as data1,
   max(case when cnt = 2 then data end) as data2,
   max(case when cnt = 1 then data end) as data3
from
   (
       select
          a.cat,
          a.id,
          a.data,
          count(*) as cnt
       from
          t a,
          t b
       where
          a.cat = b.cat and
          a.id <= b.id
       group by
          a.id,
          a.cat,
          a.data
       having
          count(*) <= 3
   )
group by
    1
order by
    1;

cat    id1    id2    id3 data1      data2      data3

  1      1      2      3 foo        bar        baz
  2      4      5      7 some       random     data
  3      6      8      9 Data 1     Data 2     Data 3
  4     13     14     15 data       for        testing
  5                   16                       one
```

Comment: Nice answer. I get some sql syntax errors, but I got the idea. `<=` + `COUNT` to see how many bigger `id`s exists.

Comment: Informix does not allow subselects in the `FROM` clause, so I used a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Informix 11.50 or above , there is an option where isn't perfect, but maybe can help. Check the select at end bellow.

They will return a [multiset](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1374.htm) datatype with char() data type... where probably will create a difficult to read it, depending of the program language are you using.

Thanks to Fernando Nunes who suggest this SQL into [IIUG forum](http://www.iiug.org/forums/ids/index.cgi/read/29725)

At this moment I don't see other alternative besides complex SQLs.

```
drop table teste; 
create temp table teste ( id smallint, cat smallint, data char(10)); 
insert into teste values ( 1, 1, 'foo ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 2, 1, 'bar ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 3, 1, 'baz ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 4, 2, 'some ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 5, 2, 'random ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 6, 3, 'Data 1 ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 7, 2, 'data ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 8, 3, 'Data 2 ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 9, 3, 'Data 3 ' ); 
insert into teste values ( 10, 3, 'Data 4 ' );

select * from teste; 
select ms.* 
from 
( 
SELECT MULTISET( SELECT ITEM t.id || ',' || t.cat || ',' || t.data m1 FROM 
teste t WHERE t.cat = tout.cat) FROM (SELECT unique cat from teste) tout 
) msdrop table teste;
```

will return :

```
expression  MULTISET{'1,1,foo       ','2,1,bar       ','3,1,baz       '}
expression  MULTISET{'4,2,some      ','5,2,random    ','7,2,data      '}
expression  MULTISET{'6,3,Data 1    ','8,3,Data 2    ','9,3,Data 3    '}
```